# Comparing rates with different denominators

Tags: ratio, adjustment

I have spent quite some time looking for an answer both on cross-validated and on google, so I would greatly appreciate any hint or pointer in the right direction.

We are analyzing results collected by a different team over a span of two years, so we unfortunately cannot change the way those results were collected.

Without disclosing confidential details, we have several categories of test subjects and we calculated the rate of how many performed an action in each category.

The data looks something like this:

```
Category  | quantity of test subjects | quantity that performed the action | rate 
  A                 12500                             3577                    0.28616 
  B                 9500                              2978                    0.313474
```

We have several hundred categories and want to compare which one performed the best. Unfortunately the quantity of test subjects (the denominator) is different for each category - something we cannot change. In the example above it looks as if category B outperformed category A, but the quantity was so much lower, so it is an unfair comparison.

Is there a way to adjust/equalize for the quantity of test subjects so that the comparison of rates is fair? Which concepts or terms should I look for? ( I have been googling for adjust rate denominators and similar without success).

Comment: As a rule, the quantity that performed the action is proportional to the quantity of test subjects. The rate / proportion normalises for this so should be comparable across all categories as long as none of the categories have a small number of test subjects. In essence, using a rate is adjusting the count to account for the quantity of test subjects so you do not need to adjust the rate.

Comment: This are counts, so maybe a logistic regression is better than comparing the rates directly. You should modify for overdispersion.

Comment: What @Eumenedies said - I would add that complications appear when either the quantities that performed the action get really small or when rates  in different categories are really close - in which case the difference in rates can be purely by luck. There are methods for quantifying this "luck" factor. The keywords for searching are "population proportion test".

Comment: Thank you all very much, yes we do have rates in different categories that do get very close (with very different quantities); I'm going to search for population proportion test and look into logistic regression - thank you